# What is the structure of my Linear mixed effect model?

Tags: mixed-model

I'm planning to use a LMM for my analysis. This is new to me.
I wonder what structure my LMM has? Is it a nested random factor LMM?

[image]
As I tried to show in the graphic already, I took body length and isotopic values from organs of every individual in my sample collection.

And how can I classify it according to the McGraw and Wong (1996) Convention? In order to choose the correct ICC?

Comment: Great pictorial representation!

Answer (score 2):

Ecological data from what I understand is often non-normally distributed, so it may be best to employ a generalized linear mixed model (GLMM) instead. Your model is almost correct, but you need to nest the individual fishies in their respective species. Without any other specification of the model, it would minimum look something like this:

```
glmer(isotopic_value ~ organ + body_weight_g + (1|species/id)
```

This includes random intercepts only. For more complicated random effects modeling, [this paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v067i01) written by the author of `lme4` has all the necessary syntax on Page 7. A useful paper on GLMMs in biology and ecological data can be [found here](https://peerj.com/articles/4794/) as well.

I'm not sure what you mean by the McGraw and Wong convention, but feel free to add a comment here and I can explain if I have an appropriate answer. ICC can be found easily for GLMMs with the `performance` package, using a code like this:

```
icc(model)
```

#### Edit

Dipetkov made two really good points that I hadn't considered when I looked through your question. First, you only have **two** species here, which is much better modeled as a fixed effect (typically you want more than 5 clusters for random effects and you only have 2).

He also mentioned that because of the way I have modeled the HLM, it assumes your other IVs are similar among species. This was what I alluded to when I mentioned using the syntax from the doc I shared for more specific random effects. For example, perhaps you believe that species have varying slopes for body weight in grams. You could alternatively model it like so:

```
glmer(isotopic_value ~ organ + body_weight_g + species + (1+body_weight_g|id)
```

You will need good theory-driven reasons for your HLM design, which will drive your random slope/intercept terms.

Comment: Thank you Shawn for you quick reply. I really appreciate that! 
Yes it is ecological data. And I took different isotopic values of various molecules. So I ran separate analysis for each molecule. And I separated the fish species even. I do not want to compare them directly. I know that they are different already. 
I read many things about LMM and I don't want to report p values only but some important parameters (e.g., ICC). It is written, that one has to choose the correct ICC among 10 different ones based on the type of model. And don't know how to do that.

Comment: I ran all my analysis in R. And I used the ICC command there with my numeric data. I thought the command wants my data not my model?

Comment: Your ICC will change per model you use, so you would normally use ICC after fitting the regression. There are a number of other things you can consider reporting, such as effect sizes (a hairy subject, but this may include Nakagawa's Pseudo R2, which is available in the `performance` package I referenced, and partR2, which is an effect size for individual predictors obtained with the `partR2` package. You should also report all your point estimates, random effects structure (i.e. SD of intercepts), and other things that are listed in the article I linked.

Comment: Thanks, yes I included those 2 R²s into my reporting. But for whatever reason my data is normal distributed according to shapiro wilk tests. I tested distribution for every molecule, in every organ of a species for that. Lucky me???

Comment: Probably helpful, but I would double check your residuals to make sure they are behaving well too.

Comment: This LMM makes some strong assumptions. For example, it assumes that the within-individual correlations are the same for all pairs of tissues (brain, eyes, liver, muscle). Also, why `(1|species/id)`? From the question it seems the OP is considering only two specific species; so why make the species "random effects"?

Comment: For some reason I made the boneheaded mistake of assuming those two species were just a subset of many. You are also right about the random effects structure. I just edited my answer to try to better explain those points. Thank you for bringing them up and let me know if I should add more.

Comment: thanks. Thanks I just saw your edit. I haven't worked on my LMM for some weeks now (laptop dead). I am bit confused. So the assumption that all within-individual correlations are the same for all pairs of tissues (brain, eyes, liver, muscle) is unrealistic? My only aim is to figure out if livers differs from other organs in their isotopic ratios in every of our measured organic compounds (considering their Fish-ID). I want to indclude individuals because some if might be more active in bioconversion of these compounds.

Comment: Well my domain is psychology so I can't speak with authority on your subject, but I would imagine that fish vary by organ size and body weight. For example, a bluegill's organs and size will look very different compared to a catfish (I assume). So it may be helpful to include this as a random slope. I have edited my answer btw to include this random slope, as well as entered species as a fixed effect, as species only has two levels.